# Oracle: invalid relational operator when creating a table with check constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

im trying to create a table using oracle and i keep getting the same error again and again

ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Here is my piece of code:

```
    CREATE TABLE Joueur(
    pseudo VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    nome VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES Equipe(nome),
    nomj VARCHAR(50) CHECK (UPPER(SUBSTR(nomj, 1, 1))),
    dateNaissance DATE CHECK (to_char(dateNaissance,"YYYY/MM/DD") > '1984/01/08'), 
);
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Where is the Equipe table? Can you post that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth line has no comparison:

```
nomj VARCHAR(50) CHECK (UPPER(SUBSTR(nomj, 1, 1))),
-------------------------------------------------^
```

What do you want to check?

Also, I would write the last one as

```
dateNaissance DATE CHECK (dateNaissance > date '1984-01-08')
```

Converting to a string doesn't cause an error but it is entirely unnecessary.

And the final comma is also an error.

EDIT:

For the first comparison:

```
nomj VARCHAR(50) CHECK (SUBSTR(nomj, 1, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'),
```

Oracle comparisons are usually case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly now with the between and the changes with the date field